# Rails: Formtastic: Select-Boxes without primary blank field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

It's about Rails and Formtastic.

How can I add a select box with formtastic without an initial/primary blank field? So that the initially selected item is the first item with content.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have you tried `:include_blank => false` ?

According to this (line 718) http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic.rb that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The link is not correct anymore though.

Comment: Here is the most recent documentation http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/SelectInput

Answer (score 24):

You resolve this one of two ways:

First option: In each select box, specify if there should be a blank line or not. Options are:

```
<%= f.input :author, :as => :select, :include_blank => false %>
<%= f.input :author, :as => :select, :include_blank => true %>
<%= f.input :author, :as => :select, :include_blank => "No author" %>
```

The last version displays "No Author" as the display in the drop down, but submits the value as blank.

Second Option: Set the default in the `config/initializers/formtastic.rb`.

```
# Should select fields have a blank option/prompt by default?
# Defaults to true.
Formtastic::FormBuilder.include_blank_for_select_by_default = false
```

By default, this is set to `true` and all your drop downs will have blank options in them. Set it to false, and by default they all won't.